# Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http:/#/' cannot be created

Tags: angular, ng-build

Wondering why I get this warning if I specify --host to my 'ng serve'.

I ran

```
node.exe --max_old_space_size=10240 .\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng serve --configuration=my-dev --host shop.bmw.my.test
```

And connecting to application as http://shop.bmw.my.test:4200 suddenly stops loading the application. I see below in the console which is just a warning.

*Unhandled Navigation Error: SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http:/#/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://shop.bmw.my.test:4200' and URL 'http://shop.bmw.my.test:4200/'.*

shop.bmw.my.test is not a real domain name and just configured in /etc/hosts.